Actual nuance of 邪魔になる?
そういうの行っても邪魔になるだけだって  結婚してる
Upon being asked "Why don't you to the mixer?" the guy answer this.
"Even if I got.... I'm married."
What is the nuance of 邪魔になるhere? I will make problem? I will be bothered? Is it about his state of mind or the problems he will create there?

「結婚してる」の後はなんて書いてありますか？「結婚してるし 」ではないですよね？

邪魔になる means the subject will be nuisance to others, and it never means the subject will be annoyed. Here, 邪魔になる does not mean actively causing troubles, but rather that his mere presence will be nuisance to others (since he is married).
